# Adding an Average Calculation to the next blank row

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, average

I have been working to find a way to add a mean to the first blank cell in a column (there will be multiple blank cells in the column as it is broken into several groups but I am hoping to just loop it so after it fills the first blank it will do the same for the next blank. I want it to average C2:C6 in the image shown but the cell range is dynamic as is the number of columns. I tried to have it find the next blank row then average above it but clearly I am bad at code. The second blank is for a standard error but I'm hoping to edit the code for the mean to apply to the standard error. Also the bulk of this code is from Ambie on StackExchange  ([Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517109/excel-vba-calculate-average-of-data-with-a-dynamic-number-of-columns))
[Example of the sheet I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFMSl.png)

```
Sub MeanSEM01()


Dim nextrow As Long
nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Dim lastCol As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range

'Find the last column.
'Assumes the relevant column is the last one with data in row 5.
With Sheet1
    lastCol = .Cells(nextrow - 1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

'Iterate the columns from 1 (ie "A") to the last.
For i = 1 To lastCol
    With ActiveSheet
        'Define the data range for this column.
        'Assumes last cell from bottom of sheet is the end of data.
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(nextrow - 1, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp))
        'Write the average to the cell above.
        .Cells(nextrow, i) = WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

I also checked the Immediate Window and see that my range definition is definitely off and that's why it's failing at the Average step. I tried changing from Worksheet Function to Formula as well Range(.Cells(nextrow, i)).Formula = "=Average(rng)" but I think my range is my issue.

Comment: I also checked the Immediate Window and see that my range definition is definitely off and that's why it's failing at the Average step. I tried changing from Worksheet Function to Formula as well ```Range(.Cells(nextrow, i)).Formula = "=Average(rng)"``` but I think my range is my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I designed the code below for your easy understanding because you will have to modify it before very long.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MeanSEM01()
    ' 306

    Dim Ws          As Worksheet        ' define the sheet to work on
    Dim Rng         As Range            ' range of relevant column headers
    Dim C           As Long             ' loop counter: columns of Rng
    
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")       ' adapt the name to what you have
    With Ws
        ' in row 1, start from column C to last used cell in row 1
        ' change to suit
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With
    
    For C = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
        CalculateAvg Rng.Columns(C).Offset(1)
    Next C
End Sub

Private Sub CalculateAvg(FirstDataCell As Range)
    ' 306
    
    Dim Rng         As Range        ' Data range
    Dim Target      As Range        ' Cell to write data to

    Set Target = FirstDataCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
    With FirstDataCell.Worksheet
        Set Rng = .Range(FirstDataCell, FirstDataCell.End(xlDown))
        Target.Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(Rng)
        Target.Offset(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.StDev(Rng)
    End With
End Sub
```

Start with `Option Explicit`. You need it because you think that you don't.

'Sub MeanSEM01' is not a good name because it requires prior knowledge to be understood. Names are supposed to be descriptive, not riddles. This procedure just finds out how many columns you have. It does so by looking at the first row. Then it just calls the `Sub CalculateAvg` once for each column. Each time it passes the cell of that column but from the row below row 1 (that would be row 2, right?) to `Sub CalculateAvg` as an argument. `Sub CalculateAvg` understands this to be the first cells of the range to take the average from.

`Sub CalculateAvg` uses that first cell to find the cell to write to (`Target`), which is the first blank cell below the column of numbers of which it is the first.
It calculates the range to average from in the same way, except that it uses the last used cell instead of the next blank cell. Now worksheet functions are applied to calculate the average and standard deviation, writing the first to `Target` and the second to the cell below `Target`.

The important thing to understand is that the worksheet is defined in `Sub MeanSEM01`. The `FirstDataCell` is taken from that worksheet. `Sub CalculateAvg` knows the sheet for `Target` from `FirstDataCell`. Therefore the entire operation can be transferred to another sheet just by changing the tab name in `MeanSEM01`. Similarly, the columns can be change here: `Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))` and the `FirstDataCell` in this line `CalculateAvg Rng.Columns(C).Offset(1)`.

To run the code just call `MeanSEM01`. you will never need to call `Sub CalculateAvg`. It's for the use of `Sub MeanSEM01` only, which is why it's defined as `Private`.

Comment: I figured it out! I had to move a column without numeric data from the middle to the front :)

Comment: I replaced the StDev with StdErr using ```Function StdErr(Rng As Range) As Double
    Dim StDev As Double
    Dim Size As Integer

    StDev = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Rng)
    Size = WorksheetFunction.Count(Rng)

    StdErr = StDev / Sqr(Size)

End Function```  but now I have the issue of wanting to calculate the next groups mean and SE without including the above groups data or SE. How would I go about automating this? In my example image above I have a reference image and it shows roughly what the groupings are like between the double blanks

Comment: Most people here don't like to do follow-up questions, and I am one of those The best way is to ask a new question. That's where you have the room to explain what you need and a broader audience to give you the best answer.